# C# Dice Roll Probablity

Tags: c#

I wanted to prove that the probability of rolling a 6 on a dice is 1/6 and that the probability of rolling a 6 twice in a row is 1/36. The program I wrote was an attempt to mimic that process.

To explain my code a bit better. "attempts" is the amount of times the dice is rolled. "diceRoll" is the variable I'm using to mimic rolling a dice. "successiveAttempts" is the variable that measures if a 6 is rolled consecutively if not then the while loop is reset. The reason I have a while loop that repeats 10000 times is in order to repeat the dice roll test many times and get the average of the results. Because sometimes a 6 will be rolled twice in a row in 3 attempts or 80 attempts so I wanted to get the average of the results by repeating the process 10000 times.

The "percentage" is attempts divided by the amount of the times the test was repeated in order to get the average amount of attempts per dice roll. When I change the number inside the while loop to the number 1 it returns the number 6 in my program which is correct. It takes on average 6 attempts in order to roll a 6. But when I change the number to 2 successive attempts. I get back 42 which is untrue. The amount of attempts it should on average take to roll a 6 twice in a row is 36 attempts.

I can't figure out why the program works correctly when the number inside the while loop is 1 vs 2. Can anyone explain where I am going wrong? I am sorry if my code is confusing I am a beginner and I am very confused. If anyone could aid me I would love the help.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random numGen = new Random();
    int diceRoll = 0;
    int attempts = 0;
    int successiveAttempts = 0;
    int x = 0;

    while (x < 10000)
    {
        successiveAttempts = 0;
        while (successiveAttempts < 2)
        {
            diceRoll = numGen.Next(1,7);
            if (diceRoll == 6)
            {
                successiveAttempts++;
            } 
            else
            {
                successiveAttempts = 0;
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    int percentage = attempts/x;

    Console.WriteLine(percentage);
    Console.WriteLine(attempts);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: @Dijkgraaf `Random.Next(int,int)` uses an exclusive upper bound.  `Next(1,7)` returns a number between 1 and 6.

Comment: BJ Myers is right. Lower bound is inclusive, upper is exclusive. This is how Microsoft's Random class works. 1,7 seems correct to me.

Comment: the main thing I'd say here is: it isn't obvious what you're measure and why you expect the answer to be 36. What you are measuring is **not** "what is the probability that an arbitrary throw of n die will be n sixes"

Comment: You do not need nested loops. Use only the outer loop. After your first condition add another condition to check if successive attempts is bigger than one (3 in a row is twice 2 in a row!). If so, count it as one. Btw, pseudo random number generated by .net will probably not be as random as a dice roll. If by tomorow you will not have an accepted answer I will post an answer with correct code. (Currently writing on a tablet...)

Comment: The probability of rolling two sixes on two dice is 1/36. The probability of two adjacent rolls in a sequence being 6 is not. Consider a sequence of length 3 made up of three random rolls. There are 216 different possible sequences but only 11 contain two adjacent 6s (`x66` and `66x` for x = 1..5; and `666` is the 11th). You can clearly see therefore that your approach is flawed. What you should be doing is repeating 10000 times the rolling of two dice. If both are 6 you have a success. Count the number of success and divide by 10000 and you should get approximately 0.02777 (ie 1/36).

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that you've got the statistics totally messed up here, there are also code problems. Percentage, attempts and x are all ints, and you're dividing two of them to assign to the third, which (1) gives you an integer, not a fraction, and (2) **is not a percentage**.  Why is this thing that bears no resemblance to a percentage called "percentage"?

Comment: @Chris Shouldn't `666` be counted twice in this scenario?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Oh yeah, probably. I don't really care about rigorous so much as showing that it wasn't going to get you the right number. I probably shouldn't have said "only 11" either since that is higher than the 6 which would have been what we were looking for to "prove" 1/36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're measuring what you think you are measuring. You aren't testing separate trials to see "what is the chance of throwing N sixes?". For *that* you'd do something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Random numGen = new Random();
    int succeses = 0;

    const int TRIES = 10000;
    for(int i = 0; i < TRIES;i++)
    {
        bool allSixes = true;
        const int DICE_PER_TRY =2;
        for(int j = 0; j < DICE_PER_TRY; j++)
        {
            if(numGen.Next(1, 7) == 6)
            {
                // still good
            }
            else
            {
                allSixes = false;
                break; // might a well give up and
                       // **start the next test**
                       // (reset the test)
            }
        }
        if (allSixes) succeses++;
    }
    var triesPerSuccess = TRIES / succeses;

    Console.WriteLine(triesPerSuccess);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The main difference is that you are measuring *successive* sixes in an *ongoing* series of throws. There is no reason to suppose that the answer to that has anything to do with 1-in-36.

Comment: I might suggest upping the trials to a milliong (which is still super fast) and  changing `triesPerSuccess` to be a double so that you can see how close it is to 36 (since running a million tries gets you to within a fraction of a number of the target number which I think is much more satisfying than the smaller trials which were throwing out values as far away as 32 and 38 when cast to int on 10,000 trials).

Comment: Marc can you further clarify on where I went wrong in my logic. I have a poor understanding of statistics. Are you saying that the chance of rolling 2 successive sixes is not 1/36? I really apologize on my confusion.

Comment: @MichaelN. the chance of throwing 2 consecutive sixes **in exactly 2 throws** is 1 in 36. What I'm saying is that *this isn't what you're doing*. You're throwing **lots and lots** of dice one after the other and counting how many times there were adjacent sixes. That is a **completely unrelated** proposition. Consider 3 dice in a row - there are 216 different outcomes; 11 of them involve adjacent 6s - 66[1-5], [1-5]66, and 666 - the point is: it has nothing to do with 1/36 any more - edit: lol, that's exactly the same as Chris said - I guess it is the obvious next example

Comment: Side note: By using inner loops you are not rolling your dice 10000 times but more. In fact, I've tested my idea of using a single loop versus your implementation on rextester and found that you have somewhere between 11600 - 11700 dice roles on average.

Comment: @Zahar indeed - it is 10000 attempts to roll 6 6s. If you want 10000 rolls: divide 10000/6 ( personally I'd still leave the "reset on fail", so it would actually be a lot *less* than 10000 rolls)

Comment: I see. That also mean that three consecutive dice role of 6 would count the same as two consecutive 6 results, that would explain the difference between my implementation and yours - I'm only doing a single loop and count a success for each result of 6 that comes after another 6, meaning that 666 would count as 6 successful results.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an alternative way of doing this, try this code:

```
var n = 1000000;
var rnd = new Random();
var trials = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => new { first = rnd.Next(1, 7), second = rnd.Next(1, 7) }).ToArray();
var pairsOfSixes = trials.Where(x => x.first == 6 && x.second == 6).Count();
var probability = (double)pairsOfSixes / n;
```

That gives me values like `0.02778` which isn't too far off of `0.0277777777777778` (the expected value).

Comment: Why the unnecessary `ToArray()`? You don't need to eagerly evaluate the enumerable and store all of them in memory at once to count them. Also `Where(x => x.first == 6 && x.second == 6).Count()` can be replaced with `Count(x => x.first == 6 && x.second == 6)`

Comment: @JoshuaWebb - I agree with both points. I tend to do the `.ToArray()` because I anticipate using the sequence more than once an don't want to be hit multiple times - especially when the sequence contains randomly generated data.

Comment: Yeah, for non-deterministic data I would call `ToArray` or similar early. Otherwise you might be tempted to so something like `successes = trials.Where(x=>x.first==x.second); failures = trials.Where(x=>x.first!=x.second);` and then these two don't actually add up to the number of trials you have since you have just generated the data twice. Lazy evaluation is good but sometimes is bugs waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, As Marc, Chris, Eric and others wrote, the chances of rolling successive numbers are different then the chances of rolling a couple of dice and getting the same number - so my answer might be redundant, but I wrote in the comments that you can do the calculation in single loop, and that I would post an answer if you would not accept one before I do, so here it is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random numGen = new Random();
    int success = 0, successiveAttempts = 0, tries = 10000;
    for( int  x = 0; x < tries; x++)
    {
        successiveAttempts = (numGen.Next(1, 7)== 6) ? successiveAttempts + 1 : 0;
        if(successiveAttempts > 1) 
            success++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} successive roles of 6 in {1} tries.", success, tries);
    Console.WriteLine("Ratio is {0}", tries/success);
}
```

Please note it still does not return the 1/36 ratio you would expect. To get that rate you should roll two dice every attempt, as demonstrated in Enigmativity's answer.